# different approaches in retrieving Caller method details apart from stack trace [Java]

Tags: java, stack-trace

There is a need to pass caller method details in java. I do not want to use StackTrace to find out them.

Are there any alternative means to get them?

I know Aspects will help but there is a concern that it will slow down performance.

Any suggestions will help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any.

In the end, you are asking for some sort of *instrumentation*. In other words: you want to tell the jvm to keep track of the call stack and more importantly, make that information available to you programmatically.

And even when you only want that to happen for specific methods, the jvm still has to track *all* method invocations, as it can't know whether one of the methods to track is called in the end. And the fact that java is interpreted and compiled to native machine code adds to the complexity, too.

So, as said: there is no way of tracking method invocations easily without performance impacts. And the tools I know that can keep that performance impact on a reasonable level, like XRebel are for later evaluation, not for programmatic consumption.

Finally: you should rather look into your requirements. Java is simply not a good language when you really need such information. It isn't meant to keep call stacks around. So: the real solution would be to either select a platform that works better for you, or (recommended) to step back and design a solution that doesn't have this requirement.